# Custom Order Menus in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu, nav

I'm using WordPress Menus for my main navigation, at the moment it's displaying the navigation alphabetically. How can I get it to display my menus in the order I have them arranged in WordPress?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com -- WordPress specific StackExchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Appearance > Menus
2. Select the menu you want to edit (this view is editing Main Nav)
3. Select that pages you want to include in your menu from PAGES on the left
4. Add To Menu

**NOTE:** You can also add post categories and nest pages within each other like shown in the image below. Make sure that your template is set up for menu nesting if you do this.

[image: Menu View]

Comment: I've done this in the order I want it and for some reason it's still displaying alphabetically. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way this is the PHP I'm using to call the Menu `code`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top-nav' , 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>`code`

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about pages in your menu, go to the editing screen and look for **Page Attributes** (typically on the lower right). You will see PARENT, TEMPLATE and **ORDER**.  In the order section, you can assign a number to the post, and they will appear in the order you define.

Hope this helps

Comment: OP specifically said Wordpress Menus which are a separate entity from using the pages as navigation links.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu page, you should just be able to drag the items into the order you want.